# Problem using distortion shader graph URP in a 2D game

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

I'm making a 2d game in a 3D environment (for z-pos parallax), I have a sprite shape and this will be the water in my game, I have a water texture graph shader, I want to set the distortion for the sprites that are behind the water plane (player, enemies, plants, e.t.c.) to make distortion "heat" effect from water, but it only works on the texture if my project is configured as URP 2D and it works the desired effect if it is configured as Universal URP.
But when configuring as Universal instead of 2D, the 2D lights cease to exist and it is impossible to use them.
My problem is that I really wanted this effect (distortion) in 2D with the 2D lights. Is there any way to change the graph shader to work or possibility to use the 2 URP together?
I had followed several tutorials on youtube but it seems it only worked on old versions of URP, how do I like to have everything up to date?!

[URP 2D Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BxL7.png)

[After Rendering Opaques and quality Settings 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F0Hf.png)

[How water looks in URP 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPOcV.jpg)

[Shader Graph with 2 modifications for URP 2D and Universal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb9sU.png)

[How water looks in URP Universal I wanted in URP 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev2pe.jpg)

[No 2D lights if Universal URP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwp5y.png)